# Django Import Task

Tags: django, import, task, djcelery

I have a tasks.py file with 3 methods defined within it.  and in my views.py file I am trying to import these methods to be called from a view.

```
from app.tasks import generate_standalone_view, generate_primary_investment_management_view, generate_funds_administration_view
```

When I call the view that calls these tasks, django returns with

```
cannot import name generate_standalone_view
```

The structure of my project is as follows

```
app-(dir)
    views-(dir)
        ajax-(dir)
            views.py

    tasks.py
```

I'm not to sure why it is having problems importing these methods.  If someone could provide some insight into what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Can you post more information about your views.py and tasks.py files?  In particular, what non-standard libraries are they importing?  I've had this problem with a circular import that involves importing your models in tasks and importing tasks in your models file.

Comment: Do you have circular import? Is your tasks importing things from views.py?

Answer (score 0):

`from project.app.tasks import ...`

Comment: You shouldn't do that, as that couples the app to the project.